# When does a Netty ChannelFuture for a write operation become "done?"

Tags: java, netty

In Netty 4, when, exactly, does the `ChannelFuture` for a write operation (let's say to an `NioSocketChannel`) become "done?" Does Netty wait for an `ACK` packet? Is there any interdependence between the input and output handlers in a `ChannelPipeline` in terms of marking write futures as done?

Comment: Netty *can't* wait for an ACK packet. Nothing in Java or the BSD sockets API allows you to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netty does not wait for `ACK` packets. `ACK` packets are an implementation detail of TCP that is mostly (entirely? yes in java, but not sure about socket api's in C) hidden to the application using a socket. If you need to know when messages are delivered you should add an acknowledge component to your application layer protocol.

In Netty 3.x, Netty would call the success method (and notify listeners) on a `ChannelFuture` after the given message was written to the socket. I'm not as familiar with the Netty 4 implementation details, but from my tracing though the source I believe this is also true in Netty 4.

[`ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove() @ ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:263`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.0.8.Final/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/ChannelOutboundBuffer.java#L263) sets the success of the future and is called by [`NioSocketChannel.doWrite(ChannelOutboundBuffer) @ NioSocketChannel.java:264`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.0.8.Final/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/socket/nio/NioSocketChannel.java#L264) after a message is done being written to the socket.

Note that being written to the socket doesn't necessarily mean the message has been sent (partially or entirely), only that it has been written to the send buffer for the socket in the TCP layer.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Sadly, it's not my protocol (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html), so it sounds like we may just need to deal with some amount of uncertainty. Cheers!