# Netty: Is ChannelFuture/ChannelFutureListener guaranteed to be "per-message"?

Tags: java, netty

I have a channel which needs to stay open because a lot of messages get written and I don't want to do a SSL-Handshake for every write.

If I would do this:

```
ChannelFuture future = channel.writeAndFlush(message1);
channel.writeAndFlush(message2);
future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener(){

    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception{

       //check for success   
    }
});

channel.writeAndFlush(message3);
```

is the assumption correct, that operationComplete will only be invoked for message1 but never for message2 nor message3?

Comment: Not in TCP, because there are no messages in TCP.

Comment: According the accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580181/when-does-a-netty-channelfuture-for-a-write-operation-become-done?rq=1) and the linked source `ChannelOutboundBuffer`indeed creates an `Entry`containing the given message and the associated future.

Comment: There is nothing in that answer about messages. It's about completed *write* operations.

Comment: Nitpicking much? From the answer I linked: "...after the given message was written to the socket". Besides: What exactly would be written other than the parameter named "message"? The term is used in the Netty-API and you knew exactly what I meant.

Comment: TCP doesn't have messages, it has a byte stream. Any use of 'message' in association with TCP cannot be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChannelFutureListener will only be executed for the ChannelFuture that was returned by a write. Each write will return another one. So yes.